# session_start() is generating the same session id everytime

Tags: php

I am trying to implement simple login and logout mechanism. When the user logs in I am creating the session by using `session_start()`. and upon the user logging out I am calling

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

but the problem is that after logging out next time if again login. `the session_id()` is same as previous. No matter how much I do the `session_destroy()`, the `session_id()` is always the same. Does it mean `session_destroy()` is not working? Or there is some other reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
session_unset(); 
session_destroy();
```

To

```
session_start(); 
session_destroy();
```

As with your code session is not really being destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/session_destroy

session_destroy() basically does

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

but leaves the session cookie, and the session ID stored in it, intact. You have to manually unset the cookie with a `setcookie()` call, or use `session_regenerate_id()` to force a new ID to be created.